# Regarding stripping slashes with text in bash

Tags: bash

I am not good in linux and I am sorry if question is very basic.

I need a command on bash shell that will return /home/barco/ext/linux-crp from /home/barco/ext/linux-crp/bin/linux-x86-32/.

I read parameter expansion but was unable to get any hint.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly clear what you want it to be based on, but

```
> string="/home/barco/ext/linux-crp/bin/linux-x86-32/"; echo "${string%/*/*/*}"
> /home/barco/ext/linux-crp
```

Would return the path two levels up (assuming the path ends in `/` and is long enough)

```
${parameter%word}
${parameter%%word}
  Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
  a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
  a  trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the
  result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter  with
  the  shortest  matching  pattern (the ``%'' case) or the longest
  matching pattern (the ``%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter  is  @
  or  *,  the  pattern  removal operation is applied to each posi‐
  tional parameter in turn, and the  expansion  is  the  resultant
  list.   If  parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or
  *, the pattern removal operation is applied to  each  member  of
  the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```